# Laravel apiResources how to call specific method

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use Laravel apiResource but obviously there is something that I can't understand of the usage.
In a simpe route you have something like that

```
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

where **show** is the method you want to call.

How can I specify which method to be called in apiResource?

Currently I have

```
  Route::apiResources(['user' =>'API\UserController']);
```

which call the **store** method in the **UserController**. I would like to specify another method to be called but for example

```
 Route::apiResources(['user' =>'API\UserController@show']);
```

is not going to call the **show** method

So how can I specify which method to be called in apiResources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a resource, `show`, `store`, `update`, `index` methods are reserved. Here is how it is going to work:

- A `GET` call on the route without any ID will call the `index()` method
- A `GET` call on the route with a resource ID will call the `show()` method
- A `POST` call on the route will call the `store()` method
- A `PATCH` call on a route with ID will call the `update()` method

The API resource route is identical to the web resource route except it doesn't come with the methods that return the views, i.e. `create()`, `edit()` etc.

If you need any custom routes, you need to define the needed routes before defining the API resource route. I hope this helps. More info is present in the [official docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!