# API Resource Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I want to understand the concept behind API resource in Laravel.  If I understand the answer I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57528645/905494). If I have a custom endpoint and there’s apiresource endpoint defined for that controller. Does the apiresource endpoint (like show, store) get called automatically when I call the custom endpoint on the controller?

Example I have this:

```
Route::post('postorderitems', 'Api\OrderitemsController@postOrderItem')->middleware('auth:api');
```

If I call it and this is defined:

```
Route::apiResource('orderitems', 'Api\OrderitemsController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Does the store method in `OrderitemsController` get called automatically?

Answer (score 1):

`Route::apiResource()` defines REST API routes for the given resource: `index`, `store`, `view`, `update` and `destroy`.

Your controller may have defined public methods with the same names as said above. If the controller has these methods then, yes, the routes will be "associated" with the controller functions.

`Route::apiResource('orderitems', 'Api\OrderitemsController')->middleware('auth:api');`

Sending POST request to `orderitems` will be handled by 
`Api\OrderitemsController@store` method.

I suggest to run `php artisan route:list` command to see to which controller's methods your routes are pointing.

[Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: I will reply but for now, I ran the commands and got an unrelate error I guess. See it here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60473018/905494

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation

> When declaring resource routes that will be consumed by APIs, you will
>   commonly want to exclude routes that present HTML templates such as
>   `create` and `edit`. For convenience, you may use the `apiResource` method
>   to automatically exclude these two routes:

```
Route::apiResource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

So If you have defined `apiResource` as below and  send `POST` request to `orderitems` then only `store` method of store method of `OrderitemsController` will be called automatically.

```
Route::apiResource('orderitems', 'Api\OrderitemsController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Controllers -> Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: So when I call postorderitems, would the store method be called too, since postorderitems is to save and there is also store?

Comment: @tksilicon, no, it's not. If you call `postorderitems` it will execute `postOrderItem` as you specified here `Route::post('postorderitems', 'Api\OrderitemsController@postOrderItem');`

Comment: Okay. So API resource is a way to define default  CRUD API endpoints and when I call a custom endpoint, it doesn't get called except I call say post or get on the controller without specifying any custom endpoint. That is what I have learned from your explanation.

Comment: Yes apiResource is used for CRUD API operations and normal routes will not be affected by it.