# Parse error: parse error, expecting `'{'' Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I ran `php artisan route:list` in eclipse folder of a laravel project and got this error. I have checked the file and there is `{` there.

```
$  php artisan route:list
```

> Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in
>   /Users/frankukachukwu/eclipse-workspace/essenceglobalmart.net/ap
>       p/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/functions/create_uploaded_file.php
>   on line 8
>
> Parse error: parse error, expecting `'{'' in
>   /Users/frankukachukwu/eclipse-workspace/essenceglobalmart.net/app/
>   vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/functions/create_uploaded_file.php
>   on line 19

```
<?php
/**
 * @see       https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2018 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (https://www.zend.com)
 * @license   https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/LICENSE.md New BSD License
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Zend\Diactoros;

/**
 * Create an uploaded file instance from an array of values.
 *
 * @param array $spec A single $_FILES entry.
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException if one or more of the tmp_name,
 *     size, or error keys are missing from $spec.
 */
function createUploadedFile(array $spec) : UploadedFile {

    if (! isset($spec['tmp_name'])
        || ! isset($spec['size'])
        || ! isset($spec['error'])
    ) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            '$spec provided to %s MUST contain each of the keys "tmp_name",'
            . ' "size", and "error"; one or more were missing',
            __FUNCTION__
        ));
    }

    return new UploadedFile(
        $spec['tmp_name'],
        $spec['size'],
        $spec['error'],
        isset($spec['name']) ? $spec['name'] : null,
        isset($spec['type']) ? $spec['type'] : null
    );
}
```

Comment: please share the `create_uploaded_file.php`

Comment: Please share what is written on create_uploaded_file.php on line 19

Comment: The error is **very** clear. And very easy to solve.

Comment: Added it @Sehdev

Comment: @tksilicon what is your php version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the package that you are using is not compatible with your `PHP` version

You need a compatible `PHP` version, which is `7.0.0 - 7.0.5 || ^7.0.7.`

To solve this issue you can either update your `PHP` version or downgrade package